# Deno plugin installing a lot of packages

Tags: npm, next.js, homebrew, webstorm, deno

I'm building a Next.js project in JetBrains WebStorm. I want to use Deno to do experiments during production. I have installed Deno using Homebrew, and I have installed the Deno plugin in WebStorm.

I tried to run a script via the IDE's run tools, and Deno seems to want to download the whole of NPM before it runs the script. Is this normal? It's making me nervous.

I guess I expect it to use node_modules for anything I'm asking it to import in my script, or the files it downloaded during the Homebrew installation just to run itself, leaving little left for it to download.

I figure that either the plugin is ignoring the Homebrew installation and downloading all Deno's own dependencies (I don't really think this is the case), or it is not finding my `node_modules` folder and it is downloading everything in my package.json file, along with the whole dependency tree, or I have done something I shouldn't have, or not done something I should have and it is literally downloading npm!

**deno.json**

```json
{
  "imports": {
    "std/": "https://deno.land/std@0.218.0/"
  },
  "tasks": {
    "dev": "deno run --watch main.ts"
  },
  "nodeModulesDir": true
}
```

**import_map.json**

```json
{
  "imports": {
    "node_modules/" : "./node_modules"
  }
}
```

I am not 100% sure I have used these config files properly.

So... does all this downloading before running the first file seem normal?

Comment: Can you share an example script you are running?

Comment: console.log("Hello, world!");

Comment: Should be totally normal if it's your first running `deno`/`npm install`, but not afterwards.

Comment: Another note is that your `import_map.json` will not work unless you link to it in `deno.json`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that's what I was doing by using `nodeModulesDir: true` and listing it in my import_map.json. I must have gotten the wrong end of the stick. How do I link it?

Comment: `nodeModulesDir` tells Deno to use the `node_modules` directory for storing packages instead of it's own cache. Import maps and the `imports` field in `deno.json` (like in your example: `"std/": "https://deno.land/std@0.218.0/"`) are the same, to link an external import map add `"importMap": "import_map.json"` to `deno.json`.